# Why is this coding behaving this way?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls, endianness

The following code prints 3, 5, 6. Can you help me understand why (and why it's not 33, 35, 36?)

```
                  global_start
                  section .data
00000000 03000000         x: dd 3

00000004 8B0D[00000000]   _start: mov ecx, [x]
0000000A 000D[16000000]   r: add byte [l+6], cl
00000010 C605[00000000]30 l: mov byte [x], 48
00000017 51               push ecx
00000018 B804000000       mov eax, 4 ; For "write" system call
0000001D BB01000000       mov ebx, 1 ; to standard output
00000022 B9[000000000]    mov ecx, x ; "buffer"
00000027 BA01000000       mov edx, 1 ; byte count
0000002C CD80             int 0x80
0000002E 59               pop ecx
0000002F E209             loop r, ecx ; decrement ecx, jump relative if not zero
00000031 BB00000000       mov ebx, 0
00000036 B801000000       mov eax, 1 ; for "exit" system call
0000003B CD80             int 0x80
```

This code is written in Assembly 8086 x32bit (NASM LISTING). RAM uses little indian.

Comment: You probably want `global _start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The code indeed stores 33, 35, 36 in x. However, when "write" system call prints x to the stdout, it prints the characters that these values represent (in ascii). And since 33, 35, 36 in HEX are the characters '3', '5', '6' respectively, then this is what's printed to the stdout.